# Casting undelete vote for my own answer

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, undelete

Currently I met with an issue in Stack Overflow.

I gave answer to this question: [enable Assertions in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324527/enable-assertions-in-objective-c/17325126#17325126) . As a quick answer I only added some-links and I was editing my answer, at that time my answer was deleted and added as a comment to the question.

I know that happened because that was a link only answer. But what happened is, when I tried to cast the undelete vote, it says moderator is deleted that post, So I can't undelete.

I read in [faqs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) that the deleted answers can be undelete by casting the undelete votes and once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.

Then why that message popped for me, when I tried to cast my undelete vote ?

**Note:**

I added my edited answer again. It solved OP's issue and he accepted that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike closing, when a moderator deletes a post, it can only be undeleted by a moderator. Regular users are not able to undelete a moderator-deleted post.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was not aware of this fact !

Answer (score 1):

> I added my edited answer again. It solved OP's issue and he accepted
>   that.

In addition to what animuson has said, once you've fixed up the post, **flag it for undeletion**. You don't need to re-post it.

Comment: Well, in this case, he's already posted a second answer...

Comment: @animuson Which isn't the correct route. Too late now, I suppose.

Comment: To be honest, posting a greatly-improved answer is probably more expedient than trying to edit and undelete in most cases; certainly less work for all involved.